# Disable CSS color highlighting Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

All of the css colors in Visual Studio have a matching underline color. Visual Studio is marking all of the IDs used in JQuery this way as well. Is there a way to disable this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the command **devenv /safemode** from the Visual Studio command prompt, I was able to track it down to the Integrated Color Picker extension. Once I disabled it everything works as normal.